# Trying to automatically open a dynamically generated CSV file from PHP script?

Tags: php, csv

I'm successfully getting the desired output in console, but the browser isn't automatically downloading the CSV file.

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv');

$filename = 'Totals Report for ' . $name . ' All-Time.csv';
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');

$output = fopen('php://output', 'rb');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('Procedure Name', 'Totals'));

foreach ($rows as $row){
    fputcsv($output, $row);
}

fopen($filename);

fclose($output);
```

Comment: You don't use file handlers at all to serve a CSV file, simply echo the data out in csv format and set your header to the appropirate mime type, i.e. `text/csv`, and the browser will know it's dealing with a download.

Comment: how do you 'echo the data out in csv format'?

Answer (score 0):

Bah, this got unruly in the comments. I took it a step further and made it loop through the values too!

```
// Set headers

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
$filename = 'Totals Report for ' . $name . ' All-Time.csv';
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');

// Column titles

echo 'Procedure Name,Totals' . "\n"; // Don't forget the newlines!

// Data

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $index => $value) {
        echo $value;

        if ($index < count($row) - 1) {
            echo ',';
        }
    }

    echo "\n";
}
```

You could also buffer it into a file so you can use `fputcsv`. That would work almost exactly as your current code, but at the end you'd have `echo file_get_contents($the_buffer_file);`

The main point is that all you need to do is output your data in CSV format, i.e. separate values by commas and a new line is a new row. It would also be smart to escape the values with quotation marks (not shown in my code).

Comment: I do not like your `Content-Disposition` type

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski what's not to like? And its from OP's question.

Comment: Ohhhhh I just noticed that you have `application/csv` as the mime type, which is incorrect -- it needs to be `text/csv`. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A sample wich running in my browser:

```
$csv= '"Procedure Name", Totals'."\n";
$rows= array(
array('aaa', 'bbb'),
array('123', '456')
);
foreach ($rows as $row){
$csv .= implode(",",$row)."\n";
}
$filename= 'Totals Report for '.$name.' All-Time.csv';
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');
die($csv);
```

Comment: works in console but not exporting/downloading in browser

Comment: still not exporting/downloading in browser